# Pagination number not showing Magento

Tags: magento, pagination, categories

Why is the pagination in Magento not showing? The toolbar shows, but it just doesn't have a  page number, like `<1 2 3 4 5>`. Can you help me find out what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

$pager->setAvailableLimit(array(20=>20,'all'=>'all'));

$pager->setShowPerPage(true);

Comment: thanks for the response sir...where do i put this code sorry newbie in magento thanks again